# CodeIgniter adds new line characters in my query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I wanted to update a column in my database table, the update should just add a numeric value to the existing one.
But this time around, I'm writing the query with **CodeIgniter Query builder**, the issue is that when I run the script, **CodeIgniter** throws an **Sql Exception** below:

```
"message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11:01:37\nWHERE `user_id` = '26'' at line 1"
```

As you can see, it added a new line character to the query string.

The **PHP** code below is the query in **CodeIgniter**

```
$userModel->set('reputations', 'reputations+10', false)
          ->where('user_id', $user_id)
          ->update();
```

One thing I noticed is that if I removed the `false` (the third parameter) which tells **CodeIgniter** not to escape the column name, there won't be any error, instead '0' will be updated at `reputation` column.

I don't know what the problem might be, I could have moved on by writing a custom query, but, I wanted to be sure that I'm not doing something wrong.

P.S: custom one will look like this:

```
UPDATE users
SET reputations = reputations + 10 WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

Note: in the above error message you might be wondering where the digits in the error came from i.e
`'11:01:37` in `'11:01:37\nWHERE user_id`
It is the value of a column in my table which is also updating along side `reputation` column.

Thanks amigos.

Comment: You need to examine the line where `11:01:37` is coming from, since you say it's updating along side the reputation column, since the `\n` is after that value, not after reputations.

Comment: Thats the problem because I have scanned all through and found no error.

Comment: Can you show how you're passing `11:01:37` into the database, or where it's coming from? It may not be an obvious error, but it's coming from whatever is updating that particular field with that value.

Comment: It's actually updated automatically by codeIgniter, each time you update a row it update. it works fine for me for all my crud till I met this recent error

Answer (score 1):

Could it be your code editor generating the newline?

Anyways, one fast way to avoid the problem is to use codeigniter query method:

```
$userModel->query("UPDATE `users` SET `reputations` = reputations + 10 WHERE `user_id` = $user_id)
```

Not the cleanest solution but it makes sure it works! :)

Mattia

Comment: Yea, it sure will work, I later found out the best way to increment a column i.e. `$model->increment('column', value)->update()`. But I still don't understand why Codeigniter have to give the error I posted earlier